# Динамическое обновление цвета ячеек в Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Добрый день. Снова нужна ваша помощь.
Не работает как надо следующий код:
XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=IsTypeCopied[0], Converter={StaticResource IntToBrushConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Класс IntToBrushConverter:

```
    class IntToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool b = (bool)value;
        if (b)
        {
            return Brushes.LightGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            return Brushes.Silver;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И есть класс Worker, реализующий INotifyPropertyChanged

```
   public class Worker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool[] _IsTypeCopied;

    public bool[] IsTypeCopied
    {
        get { return _IsTypeCopied; }
        set
        {
            _IsTypeCopied = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsTypeCopied");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Worker()
    {
        IsTypeCopied = new bool[7];
    }
}
```

Изменение IsTypeCopied происходит в следующей функции:

```
        private void gridWorker_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int index;
        try
        {
            index = gridWorker.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (index < 6) return;

        Worker SelectedWorker = (Worker)gridWorker.SelectedItem;
        if (SelectedWorker.isSelected)
            SelectedWorker.IsTypeCopied[index - 7] = true;
    }
```

При первой загрузке списка в DataGrid ячейки окрашиваются в цвет Silver. Но при изменении IsTypeCopied с false на true окраска на цвет LightGreen не происходит.
Самое интересное, если IsTypeCopied объявить через:

```
private bool _IsTypeCopied;
    public bool IsTypeCopied
    {
        get { return _IsTypeCopied; }
        set
        {
            _IsTypeCopied = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsTypeCopied");
        }
    }
```

То данный код работает как и задумано, но ячеек 7, которые необходимо окрашивать. Хотелось бы сделать это через массив.

Comment: Вам вместо массива надо использовать ObservableCollection, она оповещает всех заинтересованных об изменениях, в отличие от других коллекций

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я как раз об этом тоже подумал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблему решил при использовании массива, добавив в функцию

```
private void gridWorker_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

следующую строчку:

```
gridWorker.Items.Refresh();
```